# Remove repeating set of characters in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove the sequesnce "-~-~-" if it repeats in a string, but only if they are together.
I have tried to create a regex based on the removing of multiple white spaces regex:

```
test.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Unfortunately I was unsuccessful. Can someone please help me write the correct regex? thanks.

Example:

```
string test = "hello-~-~--~-~--~-~-"
```

output:

hello-~-~-

Another example

```
string test = "-~-~--~-~--~-~-hello-~-~--~-~--~-~-"
```

output:

-~-~-hello-~-~-

Comment: Why did someone vote this question down?

Comment: I did. There was no question, and you didn't demonstrate minimum understanding and research of the problem.

Comment: While the phrasing of the question could be better it is a relevant question and you could have edited it or asked for me to clarify, however with you 18,000 points I'm never going to win this battle with the font police, but i'll change the question anyway

Comment: That's the purpose of the downvote, to improve questions and answers by telling the reason for downvoting. I converted it to +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is:

```
test.replaceAll("(-~-~-){2,}", "-~-~-")
```

`replaceAll` replaces all occurrences matched by the regex (the first parameter) with the second parameter.

the `()` groups the expression `-~-~-` together, `{2,}` means two or more occurrences.

**EDIT**

Like @anubhava said, instead of using `-~-~-` for the replacement string, you could also use `$1` which backreferences the first capturing group (i.e. the expression in the regex surrounded by `()`).

Comment: Why not: `test.replaceAll("(-~-~-){2,}", "$1")`?

Answer (score 1):

```
test.replaceAll("(-~-~-)+", "-~-~-");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you need:

```
(-~-~-){2}
```